# Apache HttpClient not receiving all cookies?

Tags: java, apache, http, client

I posted before but now I seem to actually see the problem, just having trouble fixing it.

I am trying to login to my schools grade website, maybe even make an app for it later, and when I use Chrome to inspect the cookies being created, I get all these,

```
Cookie:appName=chippewa_falls; tool=""; selection=""; districtID=1; endYear=2011; calendarID=0; permCalendarID=0; JSESSIONID=BE5AEF51EAA72975150FC2D0F77DDE13
```

But when my program prints all the cookies it received, I only get this

- `[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: BC1BAA33BEB23DC27B7883AC24934A1D][domain: campus.chipfalls.k12.wi.us][path: /campus][expiry: null]`

here is my code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://campus.chipfalls.k12.wi.us/campus/portal/chippewa_falls.jsp");
    httpget.addHeader("Referer", "http://cfsd.chipfalls.k12.wi.us//high/");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream input = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String ln = "";
        while((ln = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("During Get - " + ln);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
    List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

Note that is just for the GET part of it,

Thanks for any help :)

Edit: I did forget to mention, it is using HTTPS, but to be honest, I don't know if that matters with apache client or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those cookies must be getting set AFTER you login, not before. Looking at the output with `wget` of the URL you have above you see this:

```
Resolving campus.chipfalls.k12.wi.us... 205.213.253.11
Connecting to campus.chipfalls.k12.wi.us|205.213.253.11|:443... connected.
WARNING: Certificate verification error for campus.chipfalls.k12.wi.us: self signed certificate in certificate chain
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=004549BDBCBDFB8289EBF859A4E743B2; Path=/campus; Secure
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 6352
  Date: Tue, 17 May 2011 06:00:38 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
Length: 6,352 (6.2K) [text/html]
```

which is the exact same thing you see. Until you actually log in you will not see the other cookies.

Comment: Thanks :) That's what I was thinking, so I fixed it about an hour before you posted, but thanks anyways. Now I have a new problem, the page uses JavaScript to print everything out, is there anyway I can still get the output? I will post a new question if I have to.

Comment: Ah, for that you'll probably have some difficulty: you might want to see what AJAX calls the page makes and then emulate those to get the content, but as far as getting the layout done right that's quite messy. There are a couple of Java browser emulator libraries (I think Selenium lets you use their browser emulator from within Java code) so you might need to go down that route.